# Vue2 extend alternative in vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

```
import Vue from "vue";
const rootVeComp = Vue.extend(VueGlobalCart);
this.vueMiniCart = new rootVueComp({
                      el: this.selector,
                      Data: {
                            jsonUrl: this.props.json,
                            cartAriaText: this.props.cartAriaText
                            }
                    });
```

I have tried createApp and defineComponent but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use extends :

```js
const comp = {
    extends: ParentComponent,
    data() {
        return {
            ...
        }
    },
    mounted() {

    },
};
```

You then pass that component to the `components` of a component, or add it has a global component with app.component() like you would do with any other component

If you want to mount that component using a selector like you seems to be doing in vue2, you could look here https://github.com/pearofducks/mount-vue-component/blob/master/index.js

and here https://github.com/pearofducks/mount-vue-component

You could also do :

```js
let app = Vue.createApp(comp)
app.mount('#myapp')
```

if you want that component to be in it's own app